# How to only set IsA for records where column IsB is not null in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame. How do I set column `IsA` only for records in `data` that have a `IsB` (not `null`)? `IsA` should be `null` for records where `IsB` is `null`.

```
data['IsA'] = (data['IsB'] == True) & (data['IsC'] == False) & (data['IsD'] == False) & (data['IsE'] == False)

| ID | IsA    | IsB    | IsC | IsD | IsE |
|----|--------|--------|-----|-----|-----|
| 1  | 0      | 1      | 0   | 1   | 0   |
| 2  | 1      | 1      | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| 3  | <null> | <null> | 0   | 0   | 0   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html) and [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notna.html) for check `NaN`s, missing values with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for set `NaN`:

Thank you @coldspeed  for idea:

```
data['IsA'] = data[['IsC', 'IsD', 'IsE']].notnull().all(1) & data['IsB'].isnull()
```

EDIT:

```
print (data)
   ID  IsA  IsB  IsC  IsD  IsE
0   1  0.0  1.0    0    1    0
1   2  1.0  NaN    0    0    0
2   3  NaN  NaN    0    0    0
3   4  1.0  NaN    1    0    1


mask = (data['IsB'] == True) & (data['IsC'] == False) & 
       (data['IsD'] == False) & (data['IsE'] == False)
#simplify
#mask = (data['IsB'] == True) & data[['IsC', 'IsD', 'IsE']].eq(False).all(1)
data['IsA'] = np.where(data['IsB'].isna(),np.nan, mask)
print (data)
   ID  IsA  IsB  IsC  IsD  IsE
0   1  0.0  1.0    0    1    0
1   2  1.0  1.0    0    0    0
2   3  NaN  NaN    0    0    0
3   4  NaN  NaN    1    0    1
```

Comment: Why not shorten the expression like this? `data[['IsC', 'IsD', 'IsE']].notnull().all(1) & data['IsB'].isnull()`

Comment: @coldspeed - Your answer still sets `IsA` to `False` when `IsB` is `nan`. :S

Comment: @dunkubok I was only following the blueprint from the question and answer here.

Comment: Okay, let me try to explain it more clearly. `IsA` should become `True` when `IsB` is `True` and `IsC`, `IsD`, `isE` are `False`. There are cases where `IsB` is `nan`. I would like to set `IsA` to `nan` for such cases.

Comment: @dunkubok - So need `data['new'] = data[['IsC', 'IsD', 'IsE']].eq(False).all(1) & data['IsB'].isnull()` ?

Comment: @dunkubok - Or `data['new'] = data[['IsC', 'IsD', 'IsE']].eq(0).all(1) & data['IsB'].isnull()` ?

Comment: `(data['IsB'] == True) & (data['IsC'] == False) & (data['IsD'] == False) & (data['IsE'] == False)` should only apply for cases where `IsB` is not `nan`. If `IsB` is `nan`, `IsA` should become `nan` too. With my current code `IsA` becomes `False` when `IsB` is `nan`.

Comment: **Pseudo-code:** IF `IsB` IS NOT `NAN` --> `IsA` = `(data['IsB'] == True) & (data['IsC'] == False) & (data['IsD'] == False) & (data['IsE'] == False)` ELSE --> `IsA` = `NAN`